# Read Domains from Text File and Open in Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, vbscript, dns

I have a list of around 100+ web pages in a text file that I have to analyze. Copying and pasting can be hectic.

I think it will be efficient to run a text file in a script that will open one domain at a time and after I close IE, it opens the next domain.

If possible, update the list and remove the ones that are visited, but if there's lot of work, I can pass on this.

Let's say there are:

```
yahoo.com
google.com
microsoft.com
```

**PowerShell** It doesn't really work, as I just dived into PowerSshell.

```
$domain = Get-Content ".\list.txt"

ForEach($element in $domain){
    $url = "$domain"
    $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $ie.Navigate($url)
}
```

**VBScript** 
This
works, but open all pages at once. Which can crash if there are that many URLs. how can I control that?

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile("list.txt")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Dim fso
do while not listFile.AtEndOfStream fName = listFile.ReadLine()

Return = WshShell.Run("iexplore.exe " &  fName, 1) 
loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Updated to include line to remove URLs that have been visited, and to bring IE window to front.

This will do it with PowerShell:

```
#VB assembly needed for function to bring IE to front
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.VisualBasic"
$domain = Get-Content "c:\temp\list.txt"

ForEach($url in $domain){

    #Start IE and make it visible
    $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $ie.Visible = $true

    #Bring the IE window to the front
    $ieProc = Get-Process | ? { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.HWND }
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($ieProc.Id)

    #Navigate to the URL
    $ie.Navigate($url)

    #Sleep while IE is running
    while($ie.visible){
        start-sleep -s 1
        }

        #Delete the URL from the file
        (type c:\temp\list.txt) -notmatch "^$url$" | out-file c:\temp\list.txt
}
```

If you want to stop the script before it is done, go to the PowerShell window and close it or hit Ctrl+C.

Comment: Thank you, and it's working.
However, it's throwing the following error when I close the browser. 
`Exception setting "Visible": "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))"
At line:8 char:11
+     while($ie.Visible = $true){
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting`

Comment: Also, let's say I run script on a text file with 100 URLs, but I'd like to stop opening the site, how do I do that after X URLs? As of now, it's keep opening the URLs until the EOF.

Comment: See the edited answer--the new while statement will avoid that.  Also, my comments mentioned that the first version would throw an exception.

Comment: If you would want to stop it you go to the PowerShell window and close it or hit Ctrl+C.

Comment: Gotcha! Yes, turning it off manually should do the job. **Thanks again.**
Please update it when you're done.

Comment: @MoA I've updated the answer--please accept it as the answer if appropriate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your VBScript fails, because you don't use the [.Run method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) correctly. The third parameter bWaitOnReturn must be set to True. As in

```
Const csFSpec = "31144615.txt"
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim goWS : Set goWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec)
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine
   goWS.Run """C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE"" """ & sLine & """", 1, True
Loop
tsIn.Close
```